# Adding Scrapy request URL into Parsed Array

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using the below Scrapy code, which is fully functioning, to scrape data from from a website. The scraper inputs a text list of product IDs, which are generated into a URL on line 10. How can I add the current start_url as an additional element to my item array?

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from site_scraper.items import SiteScraperItem

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "product"
    allowed_domains = ["site.com"]
    url_list = open("productIDs.txt")
    base_url = "http://www.site.com/p/"
    start_urls = [base_url + url.strip() for url in url_list.readlines()]
    url_list.close()

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    titles = hxs.xpath("//span[@itemprop='name']")
    items = []
    item = SiteScraperItem()
    item ["Classification"] = titles.xpath("//div[@class='productSoldMessage']/text()").extract()[1:]
    item ["Price"] = titles.xpath("//span[@class='pReg']/text()").extract()
    item ["Name"] = titles.xpath("//span[@itemprop='name']/text()").extract()
    try:
        titles.xpath("//link[@itemprop='availability']/@href").extract()[0] == 'http://schema.org/InStock'
        item ["Availability"] = 'In Stock'
    except:
        item ["Availability"] = 'Out of Stock'
    if len(item ["Name"]) == 0:
        item ["OnlineStatus"] = 'Offline'
        item ["Availability"] = ''
    else:
        item ["OnlineStatus"] = 'Online'
    items.append(item)
    return items
```

I am exporting this data to CSV using the below command line code and would like the URL to be an additional value in my CSV file.

`scrapy crawl product -o items.csv -t csv`

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new [`Field`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#scrapy.item.Field) to your `SiteScraperItem` [`Item`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#scrapy.item.Item) class and set it to [`response.url`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.url) in the `parse()` method.